# how to enable "Copy python" in VSCode

Tags: vscode-python

I was playing with vscode settings and I disabled "copy python" functionality by mistake and I don't know how to re-enable it again :-(

just to be clear the functionality that I'm talking about is that for example I have this file:

```
# package_path/sub_folder/file.py

class Awesome:
    pass
```

then I right click on Awesome, then click on "copy python", a string like `from package_path.sub_folder.file import Awesome` would be copied to memory or if I right click in the file (in the explorer view) and then click on "copy python", `package_path.sub_folder.file` would be copied to memory.

any idea on how to re-enable this?

FWIW: google hasn't been helpful at all :-(

thanks in advance!